# Calculate the phase shift of a discrete sinusoid

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have a discrete sinusoid in the form:

$x(n)=Acos(\omega n+\phi )$

and I want to derive a way to calculate the phase shift $\phi$, only given x(n) at one instant and the value of the frequency.
Can you help me?

Comment: Without knowing $A$, you can't. And even so, the sign will remain indeterminate.

Comment: If I also had the value of x(n) at another instant of time?

Answer (score 0):

If you know two $x$'s,

$$x_1=A\cos(\theta_1+\phi)$$

$$x_2=A\cos(\theta_2+\phi)$$

take the ratio

$$\frac{x_1}{x_2}=\frac{\cos(\theta_1+\phi)}{\cos(\theta_2+\phi)}=\frac{\cos(\theta_2+\delta+\phi)}{\cos(\theta_2+\phi)}=\cos\delta-\tan(\theta_2+\phi)\sin\delta$$

allows you to find possible values of $\phi$, but an indetermination remains.

Comment: Thanks. However, the x(n) at the second instant of time belongs to the same sinusoid, so there is one single frequency

Comment: @Jhdoe: why do you say that ?

Comment: Because in the problem im interested in we have only the sinusoid $x(n)=Acos(\omega n+\phi )$  and given x(n1),x(n2) and $\omega$ i want to calculate $\phi $

Comment: @Jhdoe: don't you like my solution ?

Comment: My book says [this](https://ibb.co/Tt9ZGc8). Is this equal to your formula ?

Comment: @Jhdoe: of course.

Comment: Thanks so much :) So what is the indetermination ?

Comment: @Jhdoe: $k\pi$.

Comment: I thought the indetermination was about the sign :S

Comment: @Jhdoe: haha, you changed the question !

Comment: With all the info i gave, what is the indetermination ?

Comment: @Jhdoe: I said $k\pi$, didn't I ???